# Calculating number of binaries with X number of '1' digits, given a range.

Tags: combinatorics, binary

I would like to know if anyone can give me an algorithm or formula to solve the following problem:

Given two binary numbers A and C, such that C>A and both have a X number of '1' digits, how many binaries B are there, such that C>B>A and B also has exactly X number of '1' digits?

Example: For A=01001 and C=10100, there are 4 binaries with 2 '1' digits:
01010,01100,10001,10010.

If A and C would be the limits for its' number of digits (for example 000111 and 111000) it would be easy to calculate. Problem I'm having is that A and C can end on other numbers.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please tell us what you tried.

Comment: You can interpret the 1s as "separators" and 0s as values, to map for instance 01001 to 120 and 10100 to 012. Then you're asking how many 3-digit numbers there are between 012 and 120 with digits adding to 3.

Comment: Thank you! This is a problem I have while trying to develop a program. I have an algorithm that generates the next binary B with X '1's, but it would be more efficient if i knew how many times i would have to iterate, since right now i always have to check if B has reached C yet

Comment: Checking whether B equals C is cheap, and not much more expensive than a for-loop with a condition on some iterator i. If you are worried about efficiency, don't be.

Comment: A B and C are arrays so it's not as quick as checking 2 integers i think. Also, the numbers can be huge, meaning i might be forced to generate the next B millions of times. Still, i do agree it's probably still fine. However my curiosity remains. Seems to me like a combinatorics problem where you only want some fraction of the combinations

Comment: I did not understand how you mapped 01001 to 120 and 10100 to 012

Comment: @Eduard Read 01001 as "0,00," so first one zero, then two zeros, and finally no zeros (120). Similarly 10100 read as ",0,00" means no zeros before the first separator, one after that, and two after the final one (012). Your four numbers in-between these two are exactly (012), 021, 030, 102, 111, (120).

Comment: Actually what you are looking for can be found here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets. There's a slightly different mapping given there, but what you are asking is essentially to enumerate 2-subsets from a 5-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to be able to determine, for each of these binary numbers, the position it would have if you sorted all of them in increasing order. For example, when the numbers are $n=5$ digits long and $k=2$ of them are $1$'s, the list is $$00011, 00101, 00110, 01001, 01010, 01100, 10001, 10010, 10100, 11000$$ so we want a function $F$ such that $F(00011) = 0$, $F(00101)=1$, and so on.

I claim that the following rule works to do this. Given a number with digits $b_{n-1} b_{n-2} \dots b_0$, $k$ of which are $1$'s, we define:
$$
F(b_{n-1} b_{n-2} \dots b_0) = \begin{cases}
  F(b_{n-2} \dots b_0) & \text{if } b_{n-1} = 0, \\
 \binom{n-1}{k} + F(b_{n-2} \dots b_0) & \text{if } b_{n-1} = 1.
\end{cases}$$
The logic is simple: if $b_{n-1} = 1$, then there were $\binom{n-1}{k}$ sequences we skipped that began with a $0$ in that position. So we should count all of those, and then find the tail's position among the sequences that begin with a $1$.

For example, this gives $$F(01010) = F(1010) = \binom{3}{2} + F(010) = \binom{3}{2} + F(10) = \\ = \binom{3}{2} + \binom{1}{1} + F(0) = \binom{3}{2} + \binom{1}{1} = 4.$$
From seeing how this calculation went and noting where we got a binomial coefficient, we can also give an alternate definition. If the $1$'s in the number $b$ are at positions $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$ from the right, then $$F(b) = \binom{a_1}{1} + \binom{a_2}{2} + \dots + \binom{a_k}{k}.$$ For example, $1001001$ has a $1$ in positions $0$, $3$, and $6$, so $$F(1001001) = \binom{0}{1} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{6}{3} = 0 + 3 + 20 = 23.$$

Now answering the original question is easy. If you want to know how many binary numbers between $A$ and $C$ have $k$ $1$'s, the answer is $$F(C) - F(A) - 1$$ because there are $F(C)$ of them smaller than $C$, but $F(A)$ of those are smaller than $A$ (and one of them is $A$).

Comment: Wow, as a mathematics lover, that was really pleasant to read and understand. It makes sense and I'll definetly implement an algorithm with this idea later. I'll be back to tell if i succeeded lol. Thank you so much and to the user TMM who provided an interesting idea and an awesome link to Multisets, which I actually didn't know were a thing.